# Quick legacy to generics conversion question

Tags: java, generics

How to declare `mixedList` with generics for such snapshot without modifying the rest of the code?

```
List mixedList = new ArrayList();
if(flagA) {
    ClassA a = new ClassA(); //comes from elsewhere
    mixedList.add(a)
} else {
    List<ClassB> bList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();  //comes from elsewhere
    mixedList = bList; //error
}
```

I can do:

```
List<Object> mixedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
if(flagA) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
    mixedList.addAll(bList);
}
```

but is there a way to avoid changing the code?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if you declare it as Object, why would you have to change the rest of the code?

Comment: @Oscar: Because `bList` is not assignable to `mixedList`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark line with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe to assign `bList` (`List<ClassB>`) to `mixedList` (`List<Object>`).

The service from which you obtained `bList` might retain a reference to it; this service will assume its list contains only `ClassB` instances. If you *were* allowed to assign that list to a `List<Object>` reference, you could then add any type of object to the list without a warning. But when the service, thinking that every element in its list was a `ClassB`, attempted to access the elements, a `ClassCastException` would be raised.

Creating a new `List<Object>`, and adding elements to it with `add()` or `addAll()`, prevents this "type pollution". You can safely modify this copy of the list, and let the source of the list keep its own copy "pure."

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it can be done.

Rant:

Java Generics imo are simply *not worth the headache* beyond simple collection use.  **I can live with casts**. And as we all know, generics give the veneer of type safety but under the covers there is type monkey patching.

/Rant done:

This works but you will need to do reference swizzling for one of the respective block - here I'm opting for a `List<?>` for `mixedList` and swizzling for the case `flagA`:

```
public static void foo(boolean flagA) {
    List<?> mixedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if(flagA) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA(); //comes from elsewhere
        List<Object> mixedList2 = (List<Object>) mixedList; // mod
        mixedList2.add(a);
    } else {
        List<ClassB> bList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();  //comes from elsewhere
        mixedList = bList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to know what you are asking, especially the part about "not changing the code" (why ask a question then). Nevertheless, it seems you can give some bounding to Class for your list:

```
List<? extends Class<?>> mixedList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
List<Class<String>> bList = new ArrayList<Class<String>>(); 
bList.add(String.class);
mixedList = bList;
```

This code compiles (String used for easy compile check)

Comment: That doesn't look like what he wants, though; you're just adding classes to the list, not objects of those classes.